# Python. Функция zip удалить лишние знаки

Tags: python, zip

Есть zip вида:

```
('20191021000000', '-41152')  
('20191021000100', '-41159.7')  
...  
('20191021235800', '-42472')  
('20191021235900', '-42481.9')
```

Необходимо избавить его от лишних символов и получить вид:

```
20191021000000 -41152   
20191021000100 -41159.7  
и т.д.
```

для последующей записи в файл. Можно перевести zip в str и затем удалить посимвольно, например так:

```
replace('(','')
```

Но при таком подходе теряется форматирование. Есть ли способ поизящней, чтобы потом не пришлось восстанавливать исходное форматирование? Спасибо.

Comment: Объясните, а что за zip? Это ведь не про архив и не про встроенную функцию zip. Можете привести пример кода с той структурой данных, пока предполагаю, что там контейнер с этим кортежом (tuple)

Comment: Это именно встроенная функция zip в данном примере это контейнер (список) кортежей. Он сделан из двух списков (list) c помощью: a=list(zip(timing,rslt)), где timing список времен, а rslt список значений соответсвующих времени.

Comment: Если у вас `a=list(zip(timing,rslt))`, то это не "зип" , а обычный список. Про него вам ответили ниже.

Answer (score 4):

```
zip_list = [('20191021000000', '-41152'), ('20191021000100', '-41159.7')]
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in zip_list:
        f.write(' '.join(i) + '\n')

# 20191021000000 -41152
# 20191021000100 -41159.7
```